# how to find out keycode value of char in javascript

Tags: javascript, delimiter, keycode

im having a slight issue, with trying to programmatically find out the keycode value of a char. this is what I have at the moment.

```
var delimiter = ',';

//some where down the page

control.keyup(function(e)
{
    var key = delimiter .charCodeAt(0);
    if(e.keycode == key)
    {
       //do something
    }
}
```

So when I press the ',' on the keyboard key has a value of 44 whilst e.keycode is 188. How to find out the keycode value of the variable delimiter ?

Comment: @KevinBowersox when I hit the ',' key on my keyboard, i want e.keycode to match my delimiter.

Comment: For reference, the `keyCode` of `,` (on my machine) is `188`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keyup` event returns a keycode not an `ASCII` code.  If you switch to the `keypress` event you can retreive the `ASCII` code.  This should match the value received by `charCodeAt` which returns the unicode value of a character, which happens to align with the `ASCII` code for the first 128 characters.  See this [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).

```
var delimiter = ',';
var key = delimiter.charCodeAt(0);
document.getElementById("test").onkeypress = function(e){
    if((e.keyCode || e.which) == key){
       alert("Cat's out of the bag! OHHH YEAH!");
    }
};
```

Comment: Is not a keyCode different to a charCode? So how can you compare `charCodeAt(0)` to `e.keyCode`?

Comment: @PaulS. It depends on the event you use, basically `charCodeAt` provides the ASCII value.  Then keyup and keydown provide a keycode specific to the browser, while keypress gives ASCII.